# Changing orientation steps back through flag dialog

Tags: bug, flags, android-app

When flagging on a question for moderator attention (other), I noticed a strange bug with the orientation.

When choosing the flag-type and focusing the text field presented after chosing other then upon changing the orientation from vertical layout to horizontal layout and back throws one back to the "choose a flag type" dialog instead of still showing the "please enter text view.